# Subject- Verb Agreement

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which of the two sentences below is correct?

- (i) *Three hours is a long time*.
- (ii) *Three hours are a long time*.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think the first one is more correct, because **three hours** is seems a single entity.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of convention, we often treat time, money, distance, or weight as a single measurement.

So, three hours *is* a long time. About 10% of the US is Muslim. So, as a matter of habit, I might say that 3.3 million of the US is Muslim. But I might also say 3.3 million US citizens are Muslims.

(And by the way, the California lottery jackpot this week is $1.4 billion!)